# switch view not show correct at elliptic type track

Tags: android

i use switch view at api 14,i modify its style,the result:[image]  ,and my thumb is:[image] ,and 
track is [image]. i see the switch source it background is rectangle. how to modify the thumb and track,so that it look good.

```
android:layout_width="200dip"
                android:layout_height="30dip"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:textOff="Off"
                app:textOn="On" 
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:id="@+id/switch_time"
                android:track="@drawable/switch_track_bg"
                android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb_bg"
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue.I got around the issue with setting thumbtext padding like follwoing
android:thumbTextPadding="20dp"

IT works similar away as the thumb offset for a seek bar.